# Classic ASP - Storing getRows array

Tags: asp-classic

Is it possible/good practice to use a getRows() array on another page by means of a session variable or another method?

I have very large search script, and I would like to use the results of the search on other pages, not just the one that built the array. I ask because I'd have to add this huge script to all the pages that need the results, pass over the search parameters by request or session, and it doesn't seem efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I'd review the workflow so that the searches could be broken up, perhaps, in different activities and then aggregate the results in a database (temporary if need be, SQL Server Express, or even SQLite). Then, I can a task that can query the aggregated results.